# Fixed size increase with repeat zone (geometry nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms

What I'm trying to achieve is a staircase that grows 10 centimeters with each iteration. However, as far as I know, geometry nodes only has *Scales* operations for increasing the size of geometry, which, as you can see in the image, results in it getting larger than 10 centimeters.

Additionally, each time I try to connect anything to the scale vector, the scaling stops completely in every iteration. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, if this is impossible to be done, or if I'm just missing something.

Can you tell me if there's a way to achieve this? By the way, for the problem, I only showed the outer walls of the staircase, but if there's a solution for the walls, I'm sure it will work for the steps as well.

[image: Setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to scale, create new cylinders with growing radii by adding to them. The vertical stacking you can achieve by adding offset to a newly created ring. The *Merge by Distance* I would put outside of the *Repeat Zone*, because it does not make sense to repeat this action on each step, once at the end is enough.

[image: extending rings]

Result:

[image: result]